# Move all data to separate column when editing of row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table named Users for example. It have 32 columns.
I need add new column Data with type jsonb and move all data to this column.
Also i need to change data in Data column if any column of Users was changed.

For example i create new row: name="Test", age=43, country="Moon"... All this data must be in Data column.
I can change country on "Mars", in this case column Data must be changed too.

How to implement in in postgresql?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It would be much more efficient to create a view that simply converts the whole row into a JSON value rather than storing redundant data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In future i want to delete all columns and leave only id and data columns. I do it now for save existing information

Comment: @ks_on_v is this column going to be static? What do you need the JSON documents for? Consider leaving the data as they are and on demand generate a JSON output. Data split in columns are much easier and faster to edit than JSON documents.

Comment: Why would you want to do **that**? That makes no sense at all. Postgres is a relational database. And even though it has very good support for JSON, abusing it as a document store will only make your life (a lot) harder. You might want to read this: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. But i already have table with columns. I need to migrate to this structure.

Comment: You should keep your table with (all) the columns. Why do you think de-normalizing your data model would be an advantage?

Comment: @JimJones it going to be dynamic. I need update Data column if any simple column was changed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we have mechanism of finding. It use query for search like jsonb syntax. To support this i need provide column for search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question and comments I see no reason for replicating the data as JSON in a separated column. You should rather generate this data on demand.

But in case it is for some other reasons really necessary to replicate the data, you can create a [`TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html) that updates your new column after `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, e.g.

Test table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (name text, age int, country text);
```

Adding a new json column:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN summary json;
```

Function to update your json column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_summary() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  NEW.summary = json_build_object('name',NEW.name,
                                  'age',NEW.age,
                                  'country',NEW.country);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Trigger to execute the function

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_summary BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON t
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_summary();
```

Testing `INSERT` and `UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('test',43,'Moon');
SELECT summary FROM t;
                      summary                      
---------------------------------------------------
 {"name" : "test", "age" : 43, "country" : "Moon"}
(1 Zeile)

UPDATE t SET country = 'Mars' WHERE name = 'test';
SELECT summary FROM t;
                      summary                      
---------------------------------------------------
 {"name" : "test", "age" : 43, "country" : "Mars"}
(1 Zeile)
```

In this other [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209278/default-value-in-a-column-when-insert-a-new-row/59210313#59210313) I address a similar issue.